# HttpPostedFileBase to XmlReader.Create()

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, xmlreader, httppostedfilebase

Is it possible to take a xml file stored in a HttpPostedFileBase property (from MVC form), and create an XMLReader.Create(..,..) object, maintaining line numbers?

The example below uses a hardcoded xml file location..

Ideally XmlReader.Create(MyHttpPostedFileBase, rs);

```
 public static bool Validate()
    {
        try
        {          
            string XsdPath = @"C:\Projects\Mvc\Xsd\books.xsd";
            string XmlPath = @"C:\Projects\Mvc\Xsd\food.xml"; //replace with my HttpPostedFileBase 

            XmlSchemaSet set = new XmlSchemaSet();
            set.Add(null, XsdPath);

            XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings();
            rs.Schemas = set;
            rs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            rs.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(rs_ValidationEventHandler);

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XmlPath, rs))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) ;
            }
        }

static void rs_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {                    
       //code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure out a solution - hopefully this will help others.

The issue with creating an XmlDocument from a HttpPostedFileBase Xml upload is that the XmlDocument component does not maintain line numbers.

The solution was to create a stream from the HttpPostedFileBase and insert that into an XmlReader.Create().

The code below does two thing: validates that XML is valid, and then validates than XML meets XSD.

Note: I haven't had time to refactor the code quite yet, but it should be fairly understandable

```
public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile { get; set; }

public Stream GetXmlStream()
    {
        using (Stream inputStream = MyFile.InputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }

public class XmlValidator
{
    public string Error;

    public bool ValidateXml(Stream memoryStream)
    {
        try
        {
            string XsdPath = @"C:\Projects\Mvc\Xsd\books.xsd";
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("", XsdPath);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, settings);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

            try
            {
                document.Load(reader);
            }
            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                UploadedFile.Error = String.Format("Line {0}, position {1}: {2}", ex.LineNumber, ex.LinePosition,
                    ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
            document.Validate(eventHandler);
            reader.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaValidationException ex)
        {
           UploadedFile.Error = String.Format("Line {0}, position {1}: {2}", ex.LineNumber, ex.LinePosition, ex.Message);
        }
        return false;

    }

    private void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
    }




}
```